# Angular custom directive to transition upon hover shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a custom angular directive to transition the element when hover. however, i got `$().transition() undefined`.

What can go wrong?

```
  angular.module('plunker', [])
   .controller('AnimateCtlr', function(){      
  })
 .directive('hoverToTransit', function(){
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {    
        element.hover(
        function () {
          $(this).transition({ scale: 1.3 });
        },
        function () {
          $(this).transition({ scale: 1 });
        }
    ); 
  };

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: false,
        link: linker  
    };
});
```

plunker is here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/PriRMVZh0GLx4XdsxDsP?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transition is not native method of jquery.

you have to include transition library separately.

Like i use **[`Transit`](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)** and working Fine.

<kbd>**[`PLNKR`](http://plnkr.co/edit/INwE4YWqZRYSlBQBrEDD?p=preview)**</kbd>